# Use a string from array for 3 times only then move on to the next one

Tags: php, foreach

folks. I need a little help regarding a script I'm writing.

What I'm trying to do is use Proxy for file_get_content requests but in a loop. I'm sharing a basic example of what exactly I'm trying to accomplish. This is not the actual script just a basic example.

Let's say I have txt file name "urls_to_scrape.txt" and txt file called "proxy_list.txt".

*urls_to_scrape.txt* will contain list of urls separated by line.

```
http://example1.com
http://example2.com
http://example3.com
http://example4.com
.... so far arround 50k more.
```

*proxy_list.txt* will contain list of proxy separated by line.

```
proxy1:port
proxy2:port
proxy3:port
proxy4:port
```

But the main trick is each proxy is gonna request only 3 times only. After a proxy is used for 3 times script will move on to the next proxy. Once all the proxy is used. Script will start using proxy again from the beginning until all the urls has been complete.

This is what I wrote so far.

```
/* Get the list as array then start the loop */
foreach ( file ( "urls_to_scrape.txt" ) as $url ) {

    //Trim it to remove spaces.
    $url = trim ( $url );

    $headers = array(
        "http" => array(
            'proxy' => 'tcp://'.$proxy.'',
            'request_fulluri' => true,
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0',
            'timeout' => 10
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create( $headers );

    $content = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );

}
```

As you can see $proxy string is blank.. I can't write the proxy logic. How can I let the script to know to use Proxy from the list but just for **3 times each proxy**. Once a proxy used for **3 times then** the script will use the next proxy in the list. When all the proxy is used script **will again using proxy from the beginning**..

Comment: Could be more than 1 way to do it like use a Loop inside a Loop or maybe with a variable that counts how many links you assign to a proxy and when it's 3 change the proxy and reset the variable. Try someone of those if you want and tell us if you have any problem.

Comment: I can easily write to proxy logic same way I did with the first loop. But the proxy is only used for 3 request. Once a proxy made 3 request, script will use next proxy. Once all the proxy is used script will start using proxy from the beginning..

Can you guide me with some codes or similar examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 2 variables, like `$proxyNumber` and `$useCount`.

In the loop, check if `$useCount` reaches 3, and if it is, assign it 0 and add 1 to `$proxyNumber`

Initialize the file outside the loop, and add 1 to `$useCount` in each request.

It would be something like:

```
//Initialize variables
$proxyNumber = 0;
$useCount = 0;
$proxyList = file("proxy_list.txt");
foreach ( file ( "urls_to_scrape.txt" ) as $url ) {


    if($useCount === 3){ //Check if it have been used 3 times
        if($proxyNumber === count($proxyList)-1) {//Restart at end of the file
            $proxyNumber = 0;
        }else{ //else go to next
            $proxyNumber += 1;
        }
        $useCount = 0; //Restart number of uses to 0
    }
    $proxy = $proxyList[$proxyNumber];
    $proxy = trim($proxy); //Trim the proxy
    //Trim it to remove spaces.
    $url = trim ( $url );

    print "$url using $proxy<br />"; // This is for debug purposes only, you can remove it
    $useCount += 1; //Set this after $proxy have been set

    $headers = array(
        "http" => array(
            'proxy' => 'tcp://'.$proxy.'',
            'request_fulluri' => true,
            'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0',
            'timeout' => 10
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create( $headers );
    $content = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
}
```

The debug should return something like this:

```
http://example1.com using proxy1:port
http://example2.com using proxy1:port
http://example3.com using proxy1:port
http://example4.com using proxy2:port
http://example5.com using proxy2:port
http://example6.com using proxy3:port
http://example7.com using proxy3:port
http://example8.com using proxy4:port
http://example9.com using proxy4:port
http://example10.com using proxy1:port
```

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. 

Although I need to know one more thing, what if proxy_list is dynamic?
For better understanding in this example I added as txt file. In reality I will fetching proxy through API which will give me similar to text file also in array.

But the Proxies will changed every time I'm gonna fetch the Proxy-API. 
How can I change the proxy_array_list inside the loop?

Comment: Just get the contents each time in the loop, changing the `$proxyList = file("proxy_list.txt");` from the outside to the inside of the loop. If it's from an API, just change it to whatever you are getting the list from. The only problem I could see there is that maybe you could repeat some proxies depending in the order of updating of the API, if it adds new at the starting. In that case you could maybe reverse the order (check it).

Comment: Having it in the inside loop, fetching the API each time a foreach loop will go. That would be a trouble.